# Azure Devops Nuget Task not packing a dependent Package

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, azure-devops, nuget, azure-artifacts

I am here after spending 12 hours of trying to understand why its happening.

I have `.NetCore3.0` project (Let's call it project A) which has a package `Pluralize.Net.Core` (`.NetStandard`). 
I have another project (lets call it project B) which is using `.NetCore3.1`.

My project A is published on `Azure DevOps` artifacts using `Nuget pack` task and then `Nuget Push` task from by build pipeline. It has `Pluralize.Net.Core` in `PackageReference`.

When I am restoring Project A in Project B, it restores successfully. But when I am running the project B it gives me error that `Pluralize.Net.Core` is missing.

When I check the packages folder, it was not there.

I do not understand why its happening? I see a warning in `Nuget pack` task logs that `System.Runtime` is not available.

Before I was doing the packaging through .Net CLI using `dotnet pack` command, and publishing it on my locally hosted Package repo. Things were working fine. As soon as I moved to Azure artifacts the error appears.

Or may be, when I was on localhost the package was already installed. and when I moved to Azure I cleaned the nuget cache. I am not sure though.

Looking for good insight that why nuget will be skipping this package and whats the fix? Is it has to do something with `.netstandard` in a `.netcore` pack?

Comment: You mentioned project A is published on Azure DevOps artifacts, are you able to see the package in [Artifact feed](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/artifacts/overview?view=azure-devops)? Please provide your build pipeline (publish Project A and restore package in Project B), and detailed build log.

Comment: Any update to this issue?

Comment: I was busy with some other stuff., Thanks for your comment I will upload the logs.

Comment: @CeceDong-MSFT ProjectA nuget pack logs: https://pastebin.com/iXLpUBdz

Comment: ProjectB Restore logs: https://pastebin.com/La6D6mkH

Comment: Are you able to see the packages in Artifact feed?

Comment: The package which is missing does not reside in my local artifact repo. they exist on nuget.org.

Comment: From ProjectB Restore logs, your package is restored from [Artifact feed](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/artifacts/overview?view=azure-devops). Could you check whether the packages in Artifact feed? And how did you publish the package?

Comment: ProjectA is there in the Artifact Feeds, but the Pluralize.Net.Core (missing package) is not in the Artifact Feeds. but its there in nuget.org. I published using the nuget pack task in the pipe line.

Comment: steps:
- task: NuGetCommand@2
  displayName: 'NuGet pack - Caching'
  inputs:
    command: pack
    packagesToPack: projectA.csprokj
    versioningScheme: byPrereleaseNumber

Comment: ProjectB Restore log indicated "NotFound https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/ProjectA/index.json" "OK https://pkgs.pk.com/rep/_packaging/9e80c854-b23e-4220-9eee-f872db12917b/nuget/v3/flat2/ProjectA/index.json", so you need to check your nuget package, and try to remove&re-add the package.